# RMarkdown syntax within apa_table()

Tags: papaja

I am not sure if I am overseeing something, maybe there is an easy solution for this already (sorry if this is the case) but so far I haven't found one:

When I am passing a manually created `data.frame` to `apa_table()` with row names / column names / values containing RMarkdown syntax, for example `"$p$"` or `"$p > .001$"`, and try to knit it into a docx file, it will not work and just print it as it is. If I use `label_variable(df, p="$p$)` it does work ofc as expected, but this is my solution only for column names, not for the other locations within a table. The same also accounts for the `note = "$p$"` beneath an `apa_table()`.

I am curious if it is possible or if a solution already exists, I'd be thankful for some help on this one!
Best regards and thank you in advance
Mischa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `apa_table()` escapes characters that are special in LaTeX (e.g., `$`). You can turn this feature off by specifying `escape = FALSE`. Moreover, if you want to enable full markdown support for your table body, I recommend to specify `format = "pipe"`, which tells `apa_table()` to return the table in pandoc's *pipe* format, which in turn supports markdown.

Consider this table with some markdown commands:

```
table_content <- data.frame(
  "$\\mathit{df}$" = "$\\mathit{df} = 1$"
  , b = c("**a**", "*b*")
  , check.names = FALSE
)
```

A full call to `apa_table()` might then look like the following:

```
apa_table(
  table_content
  , escape = FALSE
  , format = "pipe"
)
```

A current limitation to this approach seems to be table notes: pandoc's pipe tables do not seem to support table notes, so using markdown syntax for the table's body while also adding a table note does not seem to work at the same time.

Comment: Oh yes, don't know why I didn't understand this one in the helper... thanks!!

Comment: Edit: For me also the table notes do work with your approach!